# Finding the row wise mean

Tags: python

So I have a dataframe as follows:
eg.:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 7 |

i need a third column which is the mean other values of y

| x | y | mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 5.5 |
| b | 4 | 4.5 |
| c | 7 | 3 |

I am able to do this for the first row but how do i do it for all rows given that my dataframe contains 100000 rows where the mean is calculated using values of other rows.

Comment: To clarify, you want to find Mean of all the rows other than the current row and set that value in the third column.

Comment: How do you calculate mean when you have 'adc' in one column and numbers in second ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate remaining mean seperately with using current value. You can calculate total sum then substitude current value then divide to remaining items counts. total sum and total count is remains the same.

```
total_sum = df['y'].sum()
total_length = len(df.index)
df.mean = (total_sum - df['y']) / (total_length - 1)
```